# I am trying to correctly make a block row within a table in a report

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I'm trying to do a block tr inside an HTML table using the Python Jinja library for Front-end. The table appears to me with the following appearance:

[image]

El código HTML es el siguiente:

```
<body>
<div id="testName">
    {{ ca['name'] }}
</div>
<br>
<div id="testDates">
    Start test Date: <span>{{ ca['start_ca'] | time_str }}</span>
    <br>
    End test Date: <span>{{ ca['end_ca'] | time_str }}</span>
</div>

{% for stage in ca['stages'] %}
    <table class="blueTable">
        <tbody style="page-break-inside: auto;" >
            <tr id="rowOne">
                <th style="font-weight:bolder;">Stage</th>
                <th colspan="5">Start Date</th>
                <th colspan="5">End Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="rowTwo">
                 <td >{{ stage.name }}</td>
                 <td colspan="5">{{stage.start | time_str}}</td>
                 <td colspan="5">{{stage.end | time_str}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #1C6EA4; color: white;">
                <th>Step ID</th>
                <th>Step</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Expected</th>
                <th>Found</th>
                <th>Not Found</th>
                <th>Expected Ok</th>
                <th>Ok</th>
                <th>Fails</th>
                <th>Overall</th>
            </tr>


            {%for step in stage.steps%}

                <tr id="filaBucle">

                        <th rowspan='{{ step[1] | size }}'>
                            {{step[0]}}
                        </th>


                            {%for s in step[1]%}

                               <th >{{s.name}}</th>
                                <td>{{s.start | time_str}}</td>
                                <td>{{s.end | time_str}}</td>
                                <td style="color:darkblue;">{{s.expected}}</td>
                                <td style="color:green;">{{s.found}}</td>
                                <td style="color:red;">{{s.not_found}}</td>
                                <td style="color:darkblue;">{{s.expected_ok}}</td>
                                <td style="color:green;">{{s.ok}}</td>
                                <td style="color:red;">{{s.fails}}</td>


                                {% if s.overall < 50 %}
                                <td style="color: red;">{{s.overall}}%</td>

                                {% elif 50 <= s.overall < 100 %}
                                <td colspan="1" style="color: brown;">{{s.overall}}%</td>

                                {% else %}
                                <td style="color: green;">{{s.overall}}%<br></td>

                                {% endif %}

                            {% endfor %}


                </tr>

                {% if step[1] | has_errors %}

                    <tr  style="color: #F3E9EB;background-color: #8E8585; border-style: hidden;">
                        <th colspan="11"> Errors Details</th>
                    </tr>

                    {%for s in step[1]%}
                        {% if s.error_detail %}
                        <tr style="color: #D22020; background-color: #D3C9C9;">
                            <th colspan="2">Step ID: {{s._id}}</th>
                            <th colspan="9"> {{s.name}}</th>
                        </tr>
                            {% for detail in s.error_detail %}
                            <tr style="color: #D22020; background-color: #D3C9C9;">
                                <td colspan="11"> {{detail | replace("\n", "<br>")}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}

                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried to do everything possible with the CSS, but everything is out of place and I can't put those rows as subsections of the first column where it is numbered

Comment: please clearly mention what you are trying to do, do you want to utilize that empty space as a tr td?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you click in "enter imagen description here" yo can see the problem. I need to make a break line in the end of the line, where is the last <td>